# Makefile project imported on Eclipse: sources not listed and unresolved inclusions

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I'm trying to import a C Makefile project on Eclipse CDT.

The project directory structure follows this arrangement:

```
+--project
|     |
|     +--code
|     |    |
|     |    +--src
|     |    +--inc
|     |
|     +--gcc
```

The Makefile resides on project/gcc.

I'm importing the project using the usual recipe: File->New->Project...->C project->Makefile Project->Empty Project (Cross GCC) and I do NOT "use default location" but my project's makefile path (project/gcc).

The project compiles fine (Project->Build All) but I've two main problems that **makes Eclipse unusable as an IDE**:

1. The program sources are not listed on the project list. It seems
   the only things listed are contents of subdirectories of
   project/gcc, not the actual sources specified on the Makefile.
2. "Unresolved inclusion" on each and one library header on the
   programs source. Correct paths are given on the Makefile by means of
   -I.

These two main issues are not resolved by reloading Eclipse after a successful compilation.

This makes me wonder: **is Eclipse completely ignoring Makefile sources and compiler paths?**

How could this be resolved?

Thanks! :)

Comment: For the unresolved issues, I found a solution that worked for me here: https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/7/development-with-gcc-and-eclipse/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't do any parsing of Makefiles to determine where the source and header files are located, what variables to `#define`, what libraries to link in, etc. By default, Eclipse only includes everything from the root directory of the project, which in your case is being chosen as `project/gcc`...you could include other directories if you really wanted to under the project's properties:

*right click the project name* > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Source Location tab > Add Folder

What you need to do, instead of making an "Empty Project", is make a "Makefile Project with Existing Code".

From there, you choose whatever toolchain you want (including Cross GCC if you want), what language(s) your project is, and the code location, which is `project`, *not* `project/gcc`.